# How do I get write permission for Nautilus?

Tags: permissions, nautilus

I have already done some changes (mainly resizing) to a couple of .jpg files in different folders, but now I get this prompted: `'image.jpg' cannot be resized. Check whether you have permission to write to this folder.` every time I try to resize an image. The weird thing is that it worked fine a couple of minutes ago and now it's asking for permission no matter in which folder I'm working in. How can I get those permissions?

All these .jpg files belong to the same user and I haven't changed any permissions in the files/folders. It just wouldn't make any changes after a couple of uses.

Disk space is not an issue, there is more than enough. I keep almost everything on an external drive.

Everything else (like creating/copying files) is working perfectly fine, only Nautilus is making trouble. As a matter of fact I tried deleting metadata and rotating images and it's working... It's just the resizing prompting for permission.

Comment: Nope; same user and I haven't changed any permissions in the files/folders. It just wouldn't make any changes after a couple of uses... weird, I know.

Comment: More than enough, I keep almost everything on an external drive

Comment: Yes, everything else is working perfectly fine, only Nautilus is making trouble. As a matter of fact I tried deleting metadata and rotating images and it's working... It's just the resizing prompting for permission.

Comment: No difference, same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kinda fixed it by changing permissions for the whole home directory to "Read-Only", then back to "Read and Write" and it started working again from there (tried to reboot as well and it still works). I literally have no clue as to what might've caused this to behave this way, but at least it's working now.